# JS: Turn CSV string, to: Object (map)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

How to code a pure JS.

To transform CSV string:

```
col1,col2\na,b\nc,d
```

Into this object structure:

```
{"a":["a","b"],"c":["c","d"]...}
```

So it can br refered by eg.: Obj.c, to return:

```
["c","d"]
```

Try to turn: `"col1,col2\na,b\nc,d";`

into an array of array: `[['a','b'],['c','d']];`

Calling this: `CSVToArray("col1,col2\na,b\nc,d",",", true);`

```
const CSVToArray = (data, delimiter = ",", omitFirstRow = false) =>
data.slice(omitFirstRow ? data.indexOf("\n") + 1 : 0).split("\n").map(v => v.split(delimiter));
```

What about turn `"col1,col2\na,b\nc,d";` into readable referral object structure (by first item on each line)?

```
var Obj =  {
               "a":["a","b"],
               "c":["c","d"],
               ...
           }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Object.fromEntries()` to turn an array of `[key, value]` into an object with `key: value` properties.

```js
const CSVToObject = (data, delimiter = ",", omitFirstRow = false) =>
  Object.fromEntries(data.split("\n").slice(omitFirstRow ? 1 : 0).map(v => {
    let fields = v.split(delimiter);
    return [fields[0], fields];
  }));

console.log(CSVToObject("col1,col2\na,b\nc,d", ",", true));
```